# Applying DIP(Dependency Inversion) to Android Activities classes

Tags: android

Does it possible to apply DIP to Android activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RoboGuice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/) to do dependency injection on Android. It uses Google's Guice framework.